# Laravel Search in Json array of objects column where date is bigger than today

Tags: json, laravel

I have Json column that stores data like this :

```
[
   {"date": "2021-02-24"},
   {"date": "2021-02-20"}, 
   {"date": "2021-04-22"},
]
```

and I would like to get the data which is only after today, closest thing i found is this :

```
$dates = Foo::whereJsonContains('dates', ["date => '2021-04-22']);
```

but this will search by exact date , how to search by greater than just like what we do with normal where like this :

```
$dates = Foo::where('date', '>', Carbon::now());
```

Comment: look at Carbon::isFuture()

Comment: Carbon::isFuture() will return boolean

Comment: You can convert your json to php array and use array_filter with Carbon::isFuture().

Comment: i would like to see if there is a way to do it directly from DB

Comment: I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do it directly from the database, but it won't be easy.

For example, from your data you can extract json data to get an array with

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(your_field, '$[*].date') AS dates
```

Here you will get `dates` as an array of string and you have to cast each of the string to date and compare them with tomorrow's date.

Once you are able to do that, you can pass the sql command in `DB::raw()`

Comment: Just tried this now, so far i get list of dates in column as ['2021-02-24', '2021-02-25'], I am stuck with this "and you have to cast each of the string to date and compare them with tomorrow's date." any idea how to do this